# Hadoop Total order Partitioning

Tags: apache, hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

Why total total order partitioning in hadoop?. Which scenario we need to take total order partitioning ?. My understanding is after multiple reducers, each reducer result will be sorted by key . then why we need to do total order partitioning. Would be great if you could share any graphical rep. of examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total order partitioning will sort the output by key across **all** the reducers. This allows you to combine output of multiple reducers and still get the sorted output. Simple example below:

**Without total order partitioning**

```
reducer 1's output: 
(a,val_a)
(m,val_m)
(x,val_x)

reducer 2's output: 
(b,val_b)
(c,val_c)
```

If you combine, the output is not sorted by key anymore.

```
(a,val_a)
(m,val_m)
(x,val_x)
(b,val_b)
(c,val_c)
```

**With total order partitioning**

```
reducer 1's output: 
(a,val_a)
(b,val_b)
(c,val_c)

reducer 2's output: 
(m,val_m)
(x,val_x)
```

If you combine, the output is still sorted by key.

```
(a,val_a)
(b,val_b)
(c,val_c)
(m,val_m)
(x,val_x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Well explained.  .Quick question..How to combine two reducer output .. are u meaning this meaning hadoop fs -cat /hadfspath/totalpartition_outputpath/*

Comment: You can use this approach to merge the reducer output files: "hadoop fs -getmerge /example_hive/merge_case local_combined.ext". This will get all files in the HDFS at the location /example_hive/merge_case, merge them, and download locally as the local_combined.ext file.